# Can still see the public method names after using Agile.net obfuscator

Tags: .net, obfuscation

I am testing some assemblies but can still see the Public Method names when using .net reflector.  Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong?  Tried using the Help but i must be doing something wrong

Answer (score 1):

By default public symbol names don't get renamed, however you can instruct Agile.net obfuscator to rename public symbol by checking 'I want to hide public symbols names' option located on the bottom of the renaming tab.

For more details please consult the [documentation](http://www.secureteam.net)